# Replacing newlines with spaces in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am writing a function to indent all lines in a string in Vim. I am trying to this by using `substitute` to replace all start-of-lines with `n` spaces:

```
function! Indent(str, n)
  return substitute(a:str, '\v^', repeat(' ', a:n), 'g')
endfunction
```

This only indents the first line, despite my use of the `g` flag. I have also tried using `\v\_^`, same result.

```
Indent("To be or not to be\nThat is the question", 2)

# => "  To be or not to be\n  That is the question"  (DESIRED OUTPUT)
# => "  To be or not to be\nThat is the question"    (ACTUAL OUTPUT)
```

How can I modify my regex to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with split and join fairly easily.

```
function! Indent(str, n)
    let l:sep = repeat(' ', a:n)
    return l:sep . join(split(a:str, "\n"), "\n".l:sep) 
endfunction
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Out of curiosity, any idea why my RegExp solution wasn't working?

Comment: Whoops, now I remember why I didn't use this, it doesn't handle the first line because there is no newline first.

Comment: Im still looking at that. My guess is `^` beginning of line doesn't actually take new lines into consideration when used in the substitute function. You could add `\n` to the regex but then you need to put it back in later. And I added the indentation manually. Thats what the `l:sep .` is at the beginning of the join.

Answer (score 1):

this should do:

```
substitute(a:str,'\n\|^','&'.repeat(' ', a:n) ,'g')
```

Comment: You know I thought I tried this… for some reason `&` was giving me an error before. Must have been something else